# Applying K fold validation for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand K fold cross validation as I'm using it for the first time for my text classification. However I'm quite confused on how to implement it in python

I have a data frame where `data` is my text to be predicted and label is the prediction values (0 or 1). I currently used a train test split approach and used Multinomial NB on the vectorized data.

```
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# split the data into training and testing datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(df['data'], df['label'], random_state=1)
vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), max_features=1000 , stop_words="english")
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)
```

I just wanted to know how can I implement a 5 fold validation in a similar way. I looked into a lot of examples but was quite confused how to do it in a right way as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Find the accuracy of 'y_pred_class' by selecting random samples from 'X_test_dtm' instead of all samples at once. Do averaging of that predictions 5 times. The average prediction is the actual accuracy of your trained model which is k fold cross validated where k = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample of how you can use `KFold`:

```
X, y = df['data'], df['label']
metrics = []

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), max_features=1000 , stop_words="English")
    X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
    nb = MultinomialNB()
    nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
    y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)

    metrics.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class))

metrics = numpy.array(metrics)
print('Mean accuracy: ', numpy.mean(metrics, axis=0))
print('Std for accuracy: ', numpy.std(metrics, axis=0))
```

- the main idea is that you can measure the model performance by 5 experiments.
- you can evaluate not only `average accuracy` but also a `standard deviation` - as smaller `std` as better the model.
- it is better to use `StratifiedKFold` instead of `KFold`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and in the for loop it must be  train_index and test_index right instead of test and train. I'm able to run the code otherwise successfully

Answer (score 2):

Just use scikit-learn

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)
KFold(random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```

Here the n_splits parameter is ommited because the default value is 5 which is what you requested!

I guess this is the easiest way. Always look up at the documentation they provide examples with code, as well as all the parameters their explanation!

Did this help?

EDIT:

The full code would look like this!

```
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
model_selection.train_test_split(df['data'], df['label'], 
random_state=1)
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
kf.get_n_splits(X_train)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    vect = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), max_features=1000 , 
    stop_words="english")
    X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
    nb = MultinomialNB()
    nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
    y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)
```